# Shopware 5 to Shopware 6 migration: memory_limit exceeded

Tags: migration, shopware, shopware6, shopware5

While trying to execute a run during the migration from Shopware 5 to Shopware 6 a memory_limit exceeded error occurs. The migration assistant crashes during the "reading" state.

Trying to increase the memory limit does not work. Also only selecting products or only orders does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error occurs, if the Shopware 6 application is in "dev" mode.

Try to set the `APP_ENV` variable in the `.env` file to "prod"

```
APP_ENV="prod"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the memory limit try also increasing the PHP max_execution_time.
Try also setting the memory limit as high as you can (not to the recommended one, but way higher).